# Trying to draw arc in canvas - weird behavior

Tags: javascript, html5-canvas, kineticjs

I am trying to make a circle out of arcs (something similar to a donut chart is what i am trying to achieve visually) and I succeeded. But, the edges look like a 4 year old drew them!

This is how i'm drawing my arcs:

```
var arc = new Kinetic.Shape({
    drawFunc: function(canvas) {
        var context = canvas.getContext('2d');

        var x = Math.round(canvas.width / 2);
        var y = Math.round(canvas.height / 2);
        var radius = 210;
        var startAngle = 1.44 * Math.PI;
        var endAngle = 1.83 * Math.PI;
        var counterClockwise = false;

        context.beginPath();
        context.arc(x, y, radius, startAngle, endAngle, counterClockwise);
        context.lineWidth = 175;
        canvas.fillStroke(this);
    },
    stroke: '#121b21',
    strokeWidth: 175
});
```

I created an example [fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/Yxu7Z/).

I am new to canvas so i figured its probably me... 
Can someone please let me know if i am doing something wrong here?

Thank you!

Comment: Is your concern the whitespace between each "wedge" piece?  Can you be more specific about what you are trying to fix?

Comment: What you need is an Arc shape.  KineticJS will be releasing this early March

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This is the thick-stroke-arc bug present in WebKit browsers. It's probably due to some rounding problem in the arc drawing code. You'll find it looks fine in other browsers most likely. For Webkit, you can use another method to draw these wedges meanwhile.

Possible workarounds:

- Use the method you have now, but put a white circle in the middle once you're done with the wedges to blot out the interior irregularities
- Use [Kinetic.Wedge](http://kineticjs.com/docs/symbols/Kinetic.Wedge.php) instead of context.arc.

Comment: I guess i trust chrome too much... Thank you!

Comment: That edit is a good idea, but i will cover the middle ones anyways, so it doesn't matter much. I was concerned about the outer lines only just left the inner ones visible to be easier to spot my point.

Comment: I think Kinetic.Wedge is the way to go! Thank you!